# css file path automatically removed using grunt

Tags: css, angularjs, gruntjs

I am creating a simple angular project in which I am using css of font-awesome.

In my index.html I added following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

and before this i executed: `bower install font-awesome --save`

Now when i execute `grunt serve` the above line for importing css is automatically removed. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of hit and trails got the solution. In bower.json under overrides we have to write following block of code, after that grunt serve won't remove that link from index.html

```
"font-awesome" : {
      "main": [
        "less/font-awesome.less",
        "scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "css/font-awesome.css"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep), which automatically injects the bower components into your index file then anything between

`<!-- bower:css -->
 <!-- endbower -->`

and

`<!-- bower:js -->
 <!-- endbower -->`

will be overwritten with each command.

Try putting your `<link>` tag out side of this.

Comment: but i have installed this component using bower, so i guess it could be used

Comment: Correct, in that case you don't need to put link into index file, grunt-wiredep task will automatically inject the fonts css file for you!

Comment: I tried but not working still. I removed the link and then executed grunt serve but the components are not loading.

Comment: Check if your grunt serve command runs the task for wiredep, It should be defined in your gruntfile.js file

Comment: try `grunt wiredep` and then check your index file if it includes the font file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91545/discussion-between-mahesh-thumar-and-rajat-nigam).

Comment: Yes i tried this after removing this link from index.html, it is not automatically included. Now i add link and again tried grunt wiredep it is removed